# jQuery: Fire click on event on a span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw a post earlier today and have been playing around with: http://arashkarimzadeh.com/index.php/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html

What I'd like to be able to do is when a span gets clicked, to fire the click event on a different element in the page:

```
<div class='editable sampleItem pointer' id='qqq'>click me!!!</div>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

sure..

```
$('.myspan').click(function(){
   $('.different-div').click();
})

$('.different-div').click(function(){alert('div click fired')});
```

Comment: And say that I wanted to choose a child node under... say I had a span called "Test" under the .different-div...

Comment: by choose do you mean click the child span 'test' ?

Comment: ok if the child span has a class of 'test' then you'd just do this:

$('.different-div .test').click();

Answer (score 0):

Check like this,

**HTML:**

```
<div class='editable sampleItem pointer' id='qqq' onclick='clickHandler()'>click me!!!</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickHandler() {
    /* You code here */
}
</script>
```